# JavaScript : how to Convert date string "Thu Apr 23 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)" to timestamp?

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, conventions

I have the following string:

```
"Thu Apr 23 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
```

Which i need to convert into timestamp. Is it possible for example with moment.js or not? And if yes, how can i do it without heavy parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, you don't need moment.js or something else, it's native js:

```
var date = new Date("Thu Apr 23 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)")

date.getTime()
```

Be aware, the timestamp is in miliseconds.. To get it in seconds, divide it by 1000.

Comment: Unix timestamp is in seconds i think. How can i get only seconds?